# Adjust width and height for iframe depending on screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have:

```
$("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
    href : 'iframe.html',
    type : 'iframe',
    padding : 5
    });
});

<li><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="iframe.html">Iframe</a></li>
```

however I would like to Adjust size of iframe depending on user screen's size.

I was trying something like:

```
width = $(window).width() -80;
heigth= $(window).height() -80;
```

Is this correct?, how to use it in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also try this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("a.iframe").fancybox({
            'width': 800,
            'height': 500,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'type': 'iframe'
        });
    });
</script>
```

ND

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function ResizeIframe(iframe) {
    var iframeBody = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument.body : iframe.contentWindow.document.body; 
    var height = (iframeBody.scrollHeight < iframeBody.offsetHeight) ? iframeBody.scrollHeight : iframeBody.offsetHeight;
    height = height + 10;
    $(iframe).height(height);
}

<iframe id="idFrm" src="URL" frameborder="0" clientidmode="Static" scrolling="no"                            height="35px" width="98%" onload="javascript:ResizeIframe(this);"></iframe>
```

I have used it and works like charm in all browsers. Call it onload of your

ND

Comment: I think I am missing something, where should i use this function?, or just put it somewhere as it is using $(iframe)?, Think I am doing something wrong

Comment: call it onload of your iframe. I have updated my reply, please check.

Comment: I tried but how to use it in `<li><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="iframe.html">Iframe</a></li>`, as is using  a link. so when clicked it shows the iframe?

Comment: No, just place this js function in one of your js files and call it from onload event of iframe HTML tag somewhere in your iframe.html file.

Comment: Hey, did this work for you? Can you please mark this as answer if it did?