# bootstrap 3 Iframe resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I'm using bootstrap 3 in one of my application. If I use `width="80%" height="420"` then my video comes with perfect size in large screens. But it is not working as responsive in small screens (mobiles) because of `height="420"`. So that I used `class="embed-responsive-item"` with `iframe`. Again same problem `iframe` is not working as responsive. Any suggestions please. I'm not familiar with `css`. Here is some stuff.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<aside class="right-side">
<section class="content">               
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div style="background-color: #ffffff;text-align:center;padding:1%;" id="tmp">
        <iframe id="crntplay" width="80%" height="420" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/id?autoplay=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8"><span id="crntplaytitle" style="margin-left:15%;text-align:left;display: block;font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold;">title</span></div>

<div class="col-md-2"><span id="crntplayviews" style="text-align:right;display: block;font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold;">views</span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section><!-- /.content -->
```

Answer (score 1):

`iframe` can't be responsive. Just the contents in them.
You could use jquery to resize the iframe based on screen resolution

[Adjust width and height for iframe depending on screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357047/adjust-width-and-height-for-iframe-depending-on-screen-size)